# Installing OpenFlow inside Ubuntu error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, glib

I'm trying to install OpenFlow in my Ubuntu machine. I'm following the steps in [link](http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/Ubuntu_Install).

When I try to run these commands:

```
cd utilities/wireshark_dissectors/openflow
make
sudo make install
```

`make` gives me the following error:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32:24: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'packet-openflow.o' failed
make: *** [packet-openflow.o] Error 1
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360635/glibconfig-h-no-such-file-or-directory) I should do this, but in my case there is a make file.

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` foo.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the required command-line parameters using `CPPFLAGS`:

```
make CPPFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)"
```

This will provide the necessary include paths to the compiler.